# Limit the search for the current language only

Tags: 8, search

I am using the default search block provided in druapl 8.2 and have languages '**english**' & '**french**' enabled on my site. However when i am doing a search on the site, the results return are for both the **EN** & **FR** version of the content. How can i limit the search for the current language only?

**FYI**: *I am not using any views or modules for performing my search but simply using the default core search module*.